# Link several form fields to a single entity field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following problem:

I'm using Symfony 2.0 (it's intended to upgrade to 2.3 as soon as it's released). I write a program for managing a library and I would like to give the user separate input fields for every author of the book. In the end, all authors should be saved in a single database field.

I tried using custom form fields, but from what the cookbook tells me, I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Best regards,
GrimReaper1908

---------Edit----------

Thanks to Cerad's answer, I could solve my initial problem. Unfortunately, I have to modify the solution in such a way, that I can distinguish between forename and surname. In the end, all data still should be saved in a single database field. Can I use a Collection within a Collection? If that's not possible or the wrong approach, maybe has another idea of how to do it?

Best regards

Comment: Can you provide any more info? Like how are the entities related? And what code do you have so far?

Comment: Basically, you will want to add a get/setListOfAuthors to your book entity which returns/accepts an array of authors.  Then use a form collection field.

Comment: @Cerad How could I miss the collection field?? Unfortunately I cannot mark your answer as the right answer because it's a comment. Anyway thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you will want to add a get/setListOfAuthors to your book entity which returns/accepts an array of authors. Then use a form collection field.